# How to update a data.frame based on information from another data.frame

Tags: r

I have two tables: `Display` and `Review`. The `Review` table contains information on reviews on products of an online store. Each row represents the date of the review as well as the cumulative number of reviews and the average rating for the product up to the date.

```
page_id<-c("1072659", "1072659" , "1072659","1072650","1072660","1072660")  
review_id<-c("1761023","1761028","1762361","1918387","1761427","1863914")
date<-as.Date(c("2013-07-11","2013-08-12","2014-07-15","2014-09-10","2013-07-27","2014-08-12"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
cumulative_No_reviews<-c(1,2,3,1,1,2)
average_rating<-c(5,3.5,4,3,5,5)
Review<-data.frame(page_id,review_id,date,cumulative_No_reviews,average_rating)
```

```
page_id        review_id          date    cumulative_No_reviews   average_rating
1072659          1761023        2013-07-11      1                       5
1072659          1761028        2013-08-12      2                       3.5
1072659          1762361        2014-07-15      3                       4
1072650          1918387        2014-09-10      1                       3
1072660          1761427        2013-07-27      1                       5
1072660          1863914        2014-08-12      2                       5
```

The `Display` table captures the data on customers’ visit to product pages.

```
page_id<-c("1072659","1072659","1072659","1072650","1072650","1072660","1072660","1072660")
date<-as.Date(c("2013-07-10","2013-08-03","2015-02-11","2014-08-10","2014-09-09","2013-08-12","2014-09-12","2015-08-12"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
Display<-data.frame(page_id,date)
```

```
page_id         date        
1072659     2013-07-10      
1072659     2013-08-03      
1072659     2015-02-11      
1072650     2014-08-10  
1072650     2014-09-09      
1072660     2013-08-12      
1072660     2014-09-12      
1072660     2015-08-12
```

I’d like to add two column to the `Display` table (call it `Display2`) in a way that it reflects the latest review information up the point of visit for each product, as follows:

```
page_id<-c("1072659","1072659","1072659","1072650","1072650","1072660","1072660","1072660")
date<-as.Date(c("2013-07-10","2013-08-03","2015-02-11","2014-08-10","2014-09-09","2013-08-12","2014-09-12","2015-08-12"),format = "%Y-%m-%d")
cumulative_No_reviews<-c(0,1,3,0,0,1,2,2)
average_rating<-c(NA,5,4,NA,NA,5,5,5)
Display2<-data.frame(page_id,date,cumulative_No_reviews,average_rating)
```

```
 page_id            date        cumulative_No_reviews   average_rating
 1072659        2013-07-10                 0                NA
 1072659        2013-08-03                 1                5
 1072659        2015-02-11                 3                4
 1072650        2014-08-10                 0                NA
 1072650        2014-09-09                 0                NA
 1072660        2013-08-14                 1                5
 1072660        2014-09-11                 2                5
 1072660        2015-08-12                 2                5
```

I would appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `data.table` join. You can join the `Review` table with the `Display` table on the condition that the `page_id`s match and the `Review` date is less than the `Display` date. For some rows of `Display` there will be multiple rows of `Review` which match according to these conditions, so with `mult = 'last'` we're just picking the last one. Since `Review` is sorted by date, this means the one with the most recent date.

```
library(data.table) # 1.12.6 for nafill (used below)
setDT(Display)
setDT(Review)

Display2 <- Review[Display, on = .(page_id, date < date), mult = 'last']
Display2
#    page_id review_id       date cumulative_No_reviews average_rating
# 1: 1072659      <NA> 2013-07-10                    NA             NA
# 2: 1072659   1761023 2013-08-03                     1              5
# 3: 1072659   1762361 2015-02-11                     3              4
# 4: 1072650      <NA> 2014-08-10                    NA             NA
# 5: 1072650      <NA> 2014-09-09                    NA             NA
# 6: 1072660   1761427 2013-08-12                     1              5
# 7: 1072660   1863914 2014-09-12                     2              5
# 8: 1072660   1863914 2015-08-12                     2              5
```

Now this output almost matches what you show in the question, we just need to remove the `review_id` column and replace `NA`s in the `cumulative_No_reviews` column with `0`s.

```
Display2[, review_id := NULL]
Display2[, cumulative_No_reviews := nafill(cumulative_No_reviews, fill = 0)][]
#    page_id       date cumulative_No_reviews average_rating
# 1: 1072659 2013-07-10                     0             NA
# 2: 1072659 2013-08-03                     1              5
# 3: 1072659 2015-02-11                     3              4
# 4: 1072650 2014-08-10                     0             NA
# 5: 1072650 2014-09-09                     0             NA
# 6: 1072660 2013-08-12                     1              5
# 7: 1072660 2014-09-12                     2              5
# 8: 1072660 2015-08-12                     2              5
```